# what's wrong with this javascript code getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have this code below..

```
<script>  document.getElementById('example').style.background-color =
'#FFCC00';    
</script>
<div id="example">This is an example.</div>
```

why does not it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The script runs before the element with the given id exists, and you have a [DOM property name](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSS2Properties) with a hyphen in it (which gets treated as the minus operator).

```
<!-- Put the element first -->
<div id="example">This is an example.</div>
<script>
    // camelCase CSS property names when converting to DOM property names
    document.getElementById('example').style.backgroundColor = '#FFCC00';    
</script>
```

See a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/eYukX/) of the above snippit.

Instead of putting the element first, you can wrap your JS statement in a function and then call it after the element exists. You can have this happen automatically by binding it as an [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) to something suitable (such as the document [load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference)).

Comment: @eawedat and did you change the css property to be camel case? What error did you get.

Comment: now it is working but the strange thing why in css we write background-color: ,, and in javascript backgroundColor even though you are changing css's style !

Comment: @eawedat — The alternative would be to design JavaScript without a nice way to subtract one number from another.

Comment: Reason why JavaScript has to use camel case is following the JS Spec with naming. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547986/can-i-use-camel-case-in-css-class-names

Comment: @epascarello — The question you link to does not appear to be related to the statement you made.

Comment: @eawedat: You can also write ``style['background-color']`` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should write backgroundColor

Comment: in proper css they write background-color , with dash

Comment: well it is only half of the answer.

Comment: @eawedat You are not writing CSS! You are writing JavaScript! JavaScript uses camel case.

Comment: yes but you are accessing ==> .style.property , it must refer to css

Answer (score 1):

2 things that need to change in your code.

1. As is, your code is in the wrong order. You need to have the HTML first and then the JS. The element doesn't yet exist in this order, the JS is being executed first and the DOM object is not yet there.
2. There is no "background-color" property. Instead use ".backgroundColor". The dashes are usually replaced with camel casing.

**Here is a working example**:

```
<div id="example">This is an example.</div>

<script>
  document.getElementById('example').style.backgroundColor = '#FFCC00';
</script>
```

**Another tip**:

If you want to remove the order as a dependency, you can wrap the JavaScript in a "onload" event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `<script>` to be below your element and use `backgroundColor`

```
<div id="example">This is an example.</div>
<script>  
    document.getElementById('example').style.backgroundColor ='#FFCC00';    
</script>
```

Comment: Same answer as another poster, only 4 minutes too late.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
<div id="example">This is an example.</div>
<script>document.getElementById('example').style.setProperty('background-color','#fco','important');</script>
```

,'important' is not required