# CSS selector notation

Tags: css

maybe a silly question but as far as I like standards I'd like to know, how should we write CSS selectors:

1. .my-selector-for-div (breaks)
2. .mySelectorForDiv (camel case)

Is there a standard which of those ( or any other ) should be used ?

Comment: It's depend of existing code style or company's standards.

Comment: so there are no general standards for it?

Comment: Local standards/formatting pertain to any code. If this contravenes global standards then as long as that doesn't break anything then it's fine because changing standards/formatting halfway through a project disrupts readability of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a website of css name convention (with examples):

http://www.realdealmarketing.net/docs/css-coding-style.php

Comment: Ok, thanks - it seems to be an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with matching the language. In CSS' case it uses hyphenation regularly so for selectors I would also use hyphens even though I personally find them ugly.

Not sure if there's a proper style guide for them though.

edit: [Can I use camel-case in CSS class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547986/can-i-use-camel-case-in-css-class-names) seems to also say use hyphens for class names.

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting articles about code formating (about CSS and BEM methodology):

http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/